# How to query Date field in Composite C1?

Tags: c#, c1-cms

I can't query the necessary item from datastore.

These are the screen outputs of used values:

```
news.CreateDate: 24.09.2014 10:39:56 
newsdate: 24.09.2014 10:39:56
```

In XML file:

```
CreateDate="2014-09-24T10:39:56.309032+03:00"
```

My initial query is below; it returns 0 item.

```
var results = Data.Get<News>().Where(h => h.CreateDate == newsdate).ToList();
```

Then I tried Like method to eliminate miliseconds if any, however I got compilation failure below; the error is: Compiler Error CS1502 - The best overloaded method match for 'name' has some invalid arguments

```
var results = Data.Get<News>().Where(h => h.CreateDate.Contains(newsdate)).ToList();
```

How can I retrive the exact news item using CreateDate field?

Comment: What values are compared in where clause? If it's strings and formats are different try to parse them to DateTime, then compare

Comment: Date CreateDate / String newsdate / I tried to compare without miliseconds but it fails in Composite C1.

Comment: try `h.CreateDate.Date == DateTime.Parse(newsdate).Date`

Comment: I've converted both sides to string and it worked.

Comment: Well good but remember that if format will be different it fails. For example if you compare "2014.01.01 00:00:01" and "2014-01-01 00:00:01" it will be not the same but actually dates are same

Comment: @NimeCloud thats a superduper bad idea! Always compare using the right types.